# hsqldb don't work after building jar

Tags: java, jar, hsqldb

`HSQLDB` works fine embedded in my Java project with `Netbeans` but running builded jar it says:

> No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:hsqlbb:file:C:\database'.

I tried to move the `hsqldb.jar` near the application jar and into the database directory with no results.

Comment: Please show us your code and clarify the exact problem so that we can provide you with an optimised solution.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like hsqldb.jar is not in your classpath.

try starting your jar like this:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar -jar yourjar.jar
```

If you want to run your jar by double clicking it, have a look in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of your jar, you could specify the classpath there. See Oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

for example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: hsqldb.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```